# how to loop row wise in a csv file in R

Tags: r

I have a csv file like this:

```
 Project Name jan feb mar apr may jun july aug sep oct nov dec
 1        proj1  23  56  76  43  22  99   76 878  54  99  43 534
2        proj2  65  68  33  76  34  66    3  78  44  78  44 778
3        proj3  72  35  21  35  38  92   26  58 745  98  67  43
```

I need a for loop which will loop through this data and  give me row wise data so that I will be able to retrieve the count of each month for each project.

Comment: Might be more efficient to do with reshaped data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `rowSums`:

```
drops <- c("Project", "Name")
df$total <- rowSums(df[, !(names(df) %in% drops)])
```

Comment: I did it in this way

library(data.table)

getdata = read.csv("ProjectData.csv")

for(i in 1:nrow(getdata)){
  execdata = getdata[i,]
  tdata <- transpose(execdata)
  abc = tdata[-1,]
  demandr <<- ts(abc,start=c(2018,1),end=c(2018,12),frequency=12)
  write.csv(demandr,"output.csv")
}